# Cannot update field of type double in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a `MySQL` table with following columns:

```
Hid     Hname    Lat                Lngt          Phone
---     -----    ---                ----          -----
Integer varchar  double(10,7)   double(10,7)  varchar
```

When I try to update the column `Hname`, `Lat`, `Longt` and `Phone`, the fields `Lat` and `Longt` (*type double*) are not updating (`Hname` and `Phone` gets updated correctly).
Can anyone help me figure out the problem? Here goes the `PHP`code segment :

```
$i=0;
foreach($chk as $A)
{
    echo $lat[$i]; echo $lon[$i]; //It displays the correct values
    mysql_query("update health_block set Lat=$lat[$i], Hname='$A', Longt=$lon[$i], Phone='$phn[$i]' where Hid=$chk1[$i]",$con);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Please show `var_dump($lat[$i]); var_dump($lon[$i]);`

Comment: It displays the type as string. I just enclosed them in quotes. It works fine now. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: check the answer below with details.

Comment: you need to check error of mysql_query()

Answer (score 1):

According to your mysql query there is typo error.

Your mysql query is

```
mysql_query("update health_block set Lat=$lat[$i], Hname='$A', Longt=$lon[$i], Phone='$phn[$i]' where Hid=$chk1[$i]",$con);
```

Your column name in the sample data is 'Lngt' and in mysql query it is 'Longt' and in `$phn[$i]` is also in single quote.

If so, use this instead

```
 mysql_query("update health_block set Lat=$lat[$i], Hname='$A', Lngt=$lon[$i], Phone=$phn[$i] where Hid=$chk1[$i]",$con);
```

The best way is to assign array items to variable first and then put it in mysql query. 
For example

```
$latitude = $lat[$i];
$longitute = $lon[$i];
$phoneNum = $phn[$i];
$check1 = $chk1[$i];

mysql_query("update health_block set Lat='$latitude', Hname='$A', Lngt='$longitute', Phone=$phoneNum where Hid='$check1'",$con);
```

Comment: Yep. But the field name is 'Longt' (as given in query). Actually the problem was that, I missed out the quotes. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("update health_block set Lat='$lat[$i]', Hname='$A', Longt='$lon[$i]', Phone='$phn[$i]' where Hid=$chk1[$i]",$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

try use {} with array variable.

> update health_block set Lat={$lat[$i]}, Hname=XXXX ... ";